# Python MediaWiki table regex (find strings of a particular format, then extract substrings within)

Tags: python, regex, mediawiki

I'm trying to find all strings of the format `{{rdex|001|001|Bulbasaur|2|Grass|Poison}}` in a large text file, and then extract the substrings corresponding to the first `001` and to `Bulbasaur`, perhaps as a tuple.

I'm assuming regex with capturing groups can be used for both; could anybody tell me the appropriate regex to use in Python 3.1 as well as a possible code outline? I'm a regex noob.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
text="""{{rdex|001|001|Bulbasaur|2|Grass|Poison}}"""
re.findall("\{\{[^|]+\|(\d+)\|\d+\|([^|]+)",text)
[('001', 'Bulbasaur')]
```

Comment: that is some fly regex right there. might i ask, where did you learn it? was it from a book/internet tutorial/divine gift? many thanks!

Comment: MSDN's regular expressions syntax page was my first impression on regex http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1400241x(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
re.match('^{{[^|]+\|([^|]+)\|[^|]+\|([^|]+)\|[^|]+\|[^|]+\|[^|]+\}}$', S).groups()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
line="{{rdex|001|001|Bulbasaur|2|Grass|Poison}}"
s=line.find("{{")
e=line.find("}}")
if s != -1 and e != -1:
    sub=line[s+2:e].split("|")
    print sub[1],sub[3]
```

output

```
$ ./python.py
001 Bulbasaur
```